# How to find out branch numbers when reverting a merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

History of my commits looks like:

```
A - B - C - D - E
     \     /
      X - Y
```

Branch `ABCDE` is `master`, branch `XY` is some other branch (say `test`), and `D` is a merge commit. `HEAD` now is at `E`. I need to return my working directory to the state of `A` on the assumption of **not** using `git reset --hard <SHA1(A)>`, only `git revert`. As far as I know, in such a case this can be done by two ways:

First way:

```
git revert --no-commit <SHA1(E)>
git revert -m 1 --no-commit <SHA1(D)>
git revert --no-commit <SHA1(C)>
git revert --no-commit <SHA1(B)>
git commit -m "Reverted to state A"
```

Second way:

```
git revert --no-commit <SHA1(E)>
git revert -m 2 --no-commit <SHA1(D)>
git revert --no-commit <SHA1(Y)>
git revert --no-commit <SHA1(X)>
git revert --no-commit <SHA1(B)>
git commit -m "Reverted to state A"
```

A stumbling block is `git revert -m`. In this example I assume that `1` allows to continue the chain of reverts along branch `master`, and `2` — along branch `test`.

The question is: how do I actually know which number means which branch?

Comment: Why don't you just `git checkout A`? If you need to switch your branch to point to A, `git checkout A; git branch -D NAME; git branch NAME; git checkout NAME`. You can still checkout any of ABCDEX or Y.

Comment: Actually I'm working with a remote repo and in this case I'm allowed only reverts and no resets and checkouts.

Comment: I would produce a patch between A and HEAD, and apply it in reverse with `patch -R`.

Comment: Aah. So you want a new commit that reverts the repo 'back in time', right?

Comment: @Kaz just what I was about to suggest!

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just revert them all at once?  Do you need to revert them singly?

Comment: @Andy But not with `patch` but rather `git apply -R`. Answer now.

Comment: @Andy Yes, you are right, that's why I try to revert commits carefully, having no ability to simply rewrite history.

Comment: @Kaz I haven't used patches before, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @BenCollins Both methods are acceptable, however, does a way of reverting them all at once exist for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect a merge commit to see who it's parents are:

```
git show <SHA1(D)>
```

The parents will be listed in the order to which you can refer to them.  This information is also printed in the output of `git log`.  Use that to deduce which commits are meant when you do `git revert -m`.

**Edit**: it seems that you're working with a public repo and looking for a way to change the a published branch, which is quite different than changing the state of a working copy.  Git has a way to revert without having to figure out each parent of merges along the way.  Just do it all at once:

```
git revert <SHA1(B)>..
```

**Update**: I was perusing some old stuff and realized this answer I gave is *completely* incorrect.  If you do the above, you will not get state A, but you will instead get a Frankenstein you don't want:

```
A - C' - D' - E'
 \     /
  X - Y
```

That ^ is the equivalent of what you'd get, which is not at all what you want.  There is really only one way to do this and preserve your history entirely:

```
git revert HEAD              # reverts E, labeled as E' below
git revert -m 1 <SHA1(D)>    # reverts D, labeled as D' below
git revert HEAD              # reverts C, labeled as C' below
git revert HEAD              # reverts B, labeled as B' below
```

This will leave you history looking like this:

```
A - B - C - D - E - E' - D'{C} - C' - B'
     \     /
      X - Y
```

This method will get you what you want and preserve every bit of history.  @Kaz and @torek's methods are more efficient and less verbose and if you don't care to ever reintroduce `X` and `Y` then I recommend one of those solutions; however, they make it potentially harder to reintroduce `X` and `Y` into your main branch, if that's something you care about.  Reverting each piece makes it possible to reintroduce `X` and `Y` without rewriting/C&P the code again, which is an attractive option if`X` and `Y` were large changes or if you are obsessive about keeping the most accurate history possible (I tend to be that way).

To reintroduce `X` and `Y`, you should do this:

```
git revert D'
```

This will likely create merge conflicts, especially if you don't also revert `B'` and `C'`, but that might be better than re-doing `X` and `Y` by hand.  Linux Torvalds wrote [a very thorough explanation of this scenario](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Git/Git-26/src/git-htmldocs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) that may be of some help to you.

Comment: Starting a new branch will not revert *that* branch to point A. Everyone will have to switch to the new branch.   He probably doesn't want to reset, either, because it's a non-fast-forward change.

Comment: Ah.  He didn't specify anything about a public repo in his question, which is pretty key.

Comment: He did specify that resetting to A is unacceptable. If these changes are not published to any other repo, there is no reason why that solution is unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to simply empty out the work tree and then insert the work-tree-as-it-was-at-commit-`A`:

```
# assumes you're in the top level
$ git rm -rf .
$ git checkout sha-or-other-specifier-for-A -- .
$ git commit -m 'revert to state A'
```

The idea here is that `git rm -rf` completely empties the work tree and index/staging-area, and then `git checkout <rev> -- .` completely re-populates the work tree and index/staging, but *gets the trees and files from the specified revision, rather than from the latest version.*

Once those two are done, a new commit writes the same trees-and-files as in commit `A`.

Answer (score 1):

I would not rack my brain over git too much in this case and just do:

```
git diff <sha(A)> HEAD | git apply -R
git commit -a -m "undoing everything since A"
```

Of course, review everything before the commit. Also, after the commit, verify: what are the differences between A and HEAD now? Ideally, nothing:

```
git diff <sha(A)> HEAD
```

Comment: @Andy Envy; revenge; clumsy daubing on a tiny smartphone screen; TCP/IP checkum inadequacy ... :)

Comment: @Kaz I just tried to upvote you but I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: There's another method that avoids needing the diff-and-apply, and is thus slightly easier (and sometimes but not always faster); I'll add that as an answer.